# Flex 3 SWC assets referenced by CSS

Tags: css, actionscript-3, flex3

I want to separate the assets from my project. So I created a project called - Styles. The style lib is separated by folders. Each folder contains the assets for a different look of the application depending on the company that will use it.

There is a CSS for each company. Basically each CSS has the same stylenames but pointing to different asset location.

Everything works great when the Styles project is linked to the project as a source path.

Once I build the styles lib, add it to the project and remove the source path it starts giving me this - cannot resolve - error for each asset.

What is the difference in the path of an asset inside an SWC? The CSS file is contained inside the same SWC. Why it recognizes the path when the project is compiled as a folder for the project, but does not once the Styles lib is used.

Comment: Does your SWC compile without errors? Can you check this. if you do right click on lib project > properties > build path > classes (All should be selected) Resources > all should be selected?

Comment: It compiles without errors and all resources are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add assets in swc and add path info in catalog.xml(in swc). In Flash Builder you can easily do it. I assume you create flex lib project for your assets

- open project->properties->build path
- add your assets folder to "source path" ( so you can see your asset folder in list which in assets tab)
- open assets tab and choose your asset folder
- build your project

after this operation you can open swc with winrar or any package reader to check your assets and catalog.xml there will be an elements in catalog.xml like

```
<file path="default.png" mod="1378205812486"/>
```

you have to use this path to load or embed your asset.

**- old conversation**

ok i missed the "cannot resolve" error. looks like you are embedding assets.it is not working because of your embedding codes are out of swc lib. swc lib is a package which keeps your actionscript classes to let you reach from main project not for the assets or other file types. but if you add all assets as class into that swc you can reach them from your project and you can easily make it with [Embed] tag.but this way css files are being useless. if you have path like this resources/img.png in your css it will always look for resources folder near swf. and this is normal it cant find the assets from swc if swc has no path info for external files

Comment: If I use your approach I need to go through my code and point the styles to the embed classes. I wanted to reference the assets by CSS. Using this class to embed my icons does not solve my errors - can't resolve source 'Embed(source='')'. Isn't there a way to reach assets from outside the main project embedding them in a SWF or SWC or some sort of lib.

Comment: i want to ask did you check your swc is there any assets in there ?if it is not you have to configure some build property for your resources project i assume you are using flash builder. and you created "flex lib projects" for your assets. first you need to add your assets folder to "source path" to see in "assets" tab. if your assets in project source(src) you dont need to do that. after this operation you need to open assets tab and need to choose assets that you are using after all these your swc will contain path info to catalog.xml. but i didnt test it with css i have no time to do that.

Comment: I opened the swc with WinRar. The assets are there. I selected them too on the assets tab. What I realized is that when I open that lib with FlashDevelop the assets are not on this symbols folder. But the EmbedClass are. Well I guess nobody has ever though of using an external asset lib. That is just weird. Thanks anyway I will look a little bit more into your answer maybe I could work something on that direction.

Comment: i checked it in flashdevelop. its showing different swc's content but you can still call assets with path. try to embed any assets with path in that swc its not giving error and you can use that asset it should work same with css too ... and you should use that paths according to catalog.xml which in swc. catalog.xml contains path info for external assets like <file path="default.png" mod="1378205812486"/>

Comment: I checked the catalog.xml. All the files are there on the section <files>
    <file path="assets/mobile/assetsCI/greyblackAssets/rightArrow58x44.svg" mod="1380715447683" />
</files>
On my css: nextMonthUpSkin: Embed(source="/assets/nxInspect/mobile/assetsCI/greyblackAssets/rightArrow58x44.svg");

Comment: I changed the path from '/assets' to 'assets' and it stop giving me the cannot encode error. But now it gives the error: exception during transoding: null. It looks like having svg files on the swc is disturbing the Flex compiler. Because the .png files are ok. I tried setting the mimetype but no change.

Comment: i found something like that http://www.actionscripterrors.com/?p=2594 use url() instead of  local() in css. can you try it. i dont know what is difference i hope it is not related with embedding

Comment: looks like this problem solved but did you resolve svg problem ? if you couldnt maybe you can upload sample(minor) project for me to check it. i have no time to create new one ...

Comment: Ok, how can I send you the project?